# Error: Function 'nf90_inq_typeid' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type; did you mean 'nf90_inq_typeids'?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, netcdf4

I am using gfortran 10.3.0 on a Mac, trying to use the netcdf4 functions for the my first time.

The functions I am trying to use are described at
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs-fortran/f90-user-defined-data-types.html

They are: nf90_inq_typeids, nf90_inq_typeid

I have a barebones routine to call that function (have only put in the inq call):

```
  subroutine assign_g(ncid, g)
    use netcdf
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: ncid
    type(gort_in_type), intent(in) :: g
    !--- Local ---
    integer :: status
    integer, pointer :: ntypes
    integer, dimension(14) :: typeidsp
 
    status = nf90_inq_typeids(ncid, ntypes, typeidsp)
    status = nf90_inq_typeid(ncid, 'pft', NF90_INT, typeidsp);
  
  end subroutine assign_g
```

I get only this error message:

```
  220 |     status = nf90_inq_typeid(ncid, 'pft', NF90_INT, typeidsp);
      |             1
Error: Function 'nf90_inq_typeid' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type; did you mean 'nf90_inq_typeids'?
```

Why isn't nf90_inq_typeid recognized?  Its installation should come with nf90_inq_typeids, no?  There is no problem recognizing nf90_inq_typeids.
On the other hand, the documentation page does not actually give a full function listing for nf90_inq_typeid with the declaration of variables, so maybe they did not finish creating this function??

In general, is there a good example somewhere of making compound types in netcdf4, creating a file with them, and assigning values?

Comment: The  line `int nf90_inq_typeid(int ncid, char *name, nf90_type *typeidp);` from the linked manual is C, not Fortran. Do you have a reason to believe it should also exist in Fortran? Do you really need it?

Comment: You can ask the compiler whether the function is available in the module `use netcdf, only : nf90_inq_typeid; end`. It will say "no", but will say so in a much clearer way. Not all C functions have Fortran implementations. You can either call the C function or ask the developers about implementing the Fortran wrapper for you.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I did not notice it was only a C function (it is on the NetCDF-fortran page..).  Was wondering if there was something wrong with my build.  Thanks.